# ERROR in org.json.JSONException: of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: json

```
  StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(
                Request.Method.POST,
                Configs.Login,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        try {
                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                            if(!obj.getBoolean("error")){

                                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                                finish();
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(
                                        getApplicationContext(),
                                        obj.getString("message"),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                                ).show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                error.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show();
                    }
                }
        )
            @Override
```

I´m getting error in the JSON format that shows

org.json.JSONException: of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

This is my JSON format

[{"id":"1","nome":"admin","email":"p_asr@hotmail.com","password":"xxxxxxx"}]

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя dont work this sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON string you mentioned starts with "[" and ends with "]". That represents an array. JSON object starts with "{"and ends with "}".

You need to get rid of square brackets surrounding the JSON string. That would solve your issue.

If that's not possible, you can create JSONArray from the string and then use first item from it to get the properties such as name and email.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
```

This should resolve your issue.

Comment: I am not near computer. But simple thing for you to do is make sure that the JSON string does not have square brackets surrounding it. If that's not possible then you can try to deserialize the JSON string to array of objects and then take the first one from the array to retrieve the properties out of it.

Comment: Ok, i will wait for you and if you done right you will receive check answer.

Comment: can you help me??

Comment: @PauloRodrigues I updated the answer about how you can use JSONArray to parse the string and then get the object out of it to access the properties. I am not JAVA developer so please pardon me for any syntax mistakes.

Comment: Changed it to zero.

Comment: W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135076/discussion-between-paulo-rodrigues-and-chetan-ranpariya).

Comment: Please be generous enough to provide reason for downvoting. That will help providing better answer next time. Thanks.